# Android Alertdialog has different size on Emultator and Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I create and show an Alertdialog that just looks fine in the emulator but looks weird in my device.

**This is how it looks like in the emulator:**

[image]

**This is how it looks like in the device:**

[image]

This is the code that i'm executing to show the dialog:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_contact, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ppc_llContact));
    tbMissatge = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.ppc_tbMissatge);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    builder.setView(layout);
    ppEnviarMsg = builder.create();


    btEnviar = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.ppc_btEnviar);
    btEnviar.setOnClickListener(this);

    ppEnviarMsg.show();


    ppEnviarMsg.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

And here the layout of the popup:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ppc_llContact"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#414145"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/ppc_lbContact"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ppc_tbMissatge"
            android:hint="@string/ppc_tooltipContact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" 
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:lines="5">
        </EditText>

        <Button android:id="@+id/ppc_btEnviar"
            android:text="@string/ppc_btEnviar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Could it maybe be related with Sense? My device is a HTC Desrie S, running ICS and Sense.
Have anyone a clue?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You might also want to try to run it in ICS emulator. The emulator in screenshot looks like something pre 2.3..

Comment: I'd recommend you to try with a dialogfragment and see how it behaves.

Comment: thanks for editing the images. Ok i'll try ICS in the emulator and i will also take a look into a dialogfragment.

I will post the results!

Comment: Change the `EditText` attribute `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `fill_parent`. It may has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be here:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_contact, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ppc_llContact));
```

You use some layout `ppc_llContact` of your Activity to be an "object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy", which is quite senseless, because this layout won't participate in final hierarchy of the dialog.

Use this instead:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_contact, null);
```

Another option is to forcibly set size of the dialog this way:

```
ppEnviarMsg.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
//FILL_PARENT is an example
```

Comment: hey, the second option did the trick! Now the problem is it appears at the top of the screen, even though i use `ppEnviarMsg.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.CENTER;`. Do you know why?

Comment: If you used `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` as in my example, then this happens because of it.
You may instead set sizes, which are relevant to the size of the screen (two thirds, for example):
`View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
ppEnviarMsg.getWindow().setLayout(decorView.getWidth() * 2 / 3, decorView.getHeight() * 2 / 3);`

Comment: Thank you, nice! I really appreciate it. I did something similar but using `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();` your snipped is probably better.